# creating tables with foreign keys and setting the navigation properties to it in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am trying to develop a web application with MVC4 but i am not able to understand how to create a table with foreign keys in it, and how to set the navigation properties to them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: are you using an ORM like Entity Framework, with code-first? Or something else? It's not at all clear. Just because you're using MVC4 doesn't place any restrictions on how you create your database. Once you decide what to use, you can consult the documentation and tutorials already available for it. As for the second part of your question, you don't navigate to tables, you create Views and navigate to those. The Views may, or may not, use some of the data from your tables, possibly in a different format to the original tables. I think you need to do some basic study of the key concepts.